# Run Python script in Django template through a button

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a very small project in Django where I get fx_rates through a Python script (details below). These are used to convert amounts in different currencies to GBP. I would like to know how I can just have a button on the website that allows to refresh this query instead of having to run it manually in the IDE. Can I create a view for this? How would I show this in a template? Thanks

fx_rates.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','fx_rates_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()


from fx_rates_app.models import fx_table

import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
os.environ["ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY"] = '#########'
fx_gbp_to_eur = web.DataReader("GBP/EUR","av-forex")
eur = float(fx_gbp_to_eur[4:5].values[0][0])


fx_gbp_to_aud = web.DataReader("GBP/AUD","av-forex")
aud = float(fx_gbp_to_aud[4:5].values[0][0])


fx_gbp_to_usd = web.DataReader("GBP/USD","av-forex")
usd = float(fx_gbp_to_usd[4:5].values[0][0])

from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

webpg1 = fx_table.objects.get_or_create(eur_to_gbp=eur,aud_to_gbp=aud,usd_to_gbp=usd,date_time=dt_string)[0]
```

In the template I included:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="run_script">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

However, I don't think the best way to do this would be to copy the all script in views with request.POST. Is there another way to leave the script in another file and just create a view to run it (e.g. if request.method == 'POST' run fx_rates.py)?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work in a view? Wouldn't you be able to put the results in the context and render them in a template? Try it, and if you have a specific problem with what you've written not working as expected, post that here with details.

Comment: @kungphu my problem is that at the moment I run the script through terminal (for every time I want to update the fx rates) however I would like to be able to run the script from the website perhaps with a button. However, I'm not sure whether this is possible and the best way to do it. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Yes, I understand. So _try putting it in a view._ There's not really anything for anyone to help with here until you can show us what you've tried and can ask specific questions about what's not working as expected.

Comment: @kungphu thanks I tried to update the question to be more specific. Apologies I know what I want to do but I don't how to translate this in Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be definitely done by creating a function `update_fx` to wrap your script and then call that function in your view.

Now for the tricky part.

Do you need the values to render them or just to update them?

Rendering will be easy, just return them from your function and you will
be able to use them in your template.

This though includes the waiting time to fetch these values. When your view will be executed you will have to wait for the function to fetch the values.

The alternative is to "trigger" a second job that updates the values from your
view. This pattern is called a task queue and there are many solutions that you can leverage already, depending on how complicated things should be (what happens if the job has an error? how many times should we retry? ...).

This also has the unfortunate effect that now you run a second python script somewhere that listens for new tasks and executes them.

As always your choice is based on tradeoffs, personally if the server has good internet connection and the request is completed fast I would not mind putting it
in my view as is.

Hope this is helpful.

Let's see an example

```py
# update.py

from fx_rates_app.models import fx_table
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime
import os

def get_price():    
    os.environ["ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY"] = '#########'
    fx_gbp_to_eur = web.DataReader("GBP/EUR","av-forex") # here we are reading stuff from the network I guess
    eur = float(fx_gbp_to_eur[4:5].values[0][0])

    fx_gbp_to_aud = web.DataReader("GBP/AUD","av-forex")
    aud = float(fx_gbp_to_aud[4:5].values[0][0])

    fx_gbp_to_usd = web.DataReader("GBP/USD","av-forex")
    usd = float(fx_gbp_to_usd[4:5].values[0][0])

    now = datetime.now()

    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    # here you have two choices,
    # either you return the raw values
    # or you put them into a model
    return {
        'timestamp': dt_string,
        'value': 1,
        'currency': 'gbp',
        'eur': eur,
        'aud': aud,
        'us': us,
    }

    webpg1 = fx_table.objects.get_or_create(eur_to_gbp=eur,aud_to_gbp=aud,usd_to_gbp=usd,date_time=dt_string)[0]
    return webpg1

# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from update import get_price

def refresh_from_values(request):
    data = get_price() # here we don't have a model, just data
    webpg1 = fx_table.objects.get_or_create(
        eur_to_gbp=data['eur'],
        aud_to_gbp=data['aud'],
        usd_to_gbp=data['usd'],
        date_time=data['timestamp'],
    )[0]
    # here your render the model using the template

def refresh_from_model(request):
    fx = get_price() # here we get back the model instead
    # you can render again the model as you can refresh the page
```

In the future you might be interested in running this thing continuously
and then you would have to move to an event driven app which is more compilicated but can be very satisfying to get right. In django everything
would start with [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) and more likely you would have to write some javascript to
update part of the page without refreshing it.

Comment: thanks for your help. Given I'm just a beginner I would prefer to keep it simple. How can I actually create a function in views to run the script from the other file?

Comment: I'll add an example for you but really is not that complicated as you will see